# how do I import a date like 2009-12-05 11:40:00 into SQL via CSV?

Tags: sql-server

I'm using the Import/Export Wizard to import some data to a table. Total of 2 rows, so I've just been working around this, but I would like to know the answer.

The issue with the Import/Export is the dates. No matter what I do, they fail. The date looks pretty straightforward to me: `2009-12-05 11:40:00`. I also tried: `2010-03-01 12:00 PM`. Tried DT_DATE and DT_DBTIMESTAMP as a source data type. The target column type is datetime.

The message that I get is:

> The data conversion for column
>   "Start_Date" returned status value 2
>   and status text "The value could not
>   be converted because of a potential
>   loss of data.".

How do I fix this? Why's the Import/Export Wizard so bad at parsing dates (or is that in my imagination)?

The truly obnoxious thing here is that when you select a date column from a table and save it as a CSV you get a date like '2009-12-05 11:40 AM'. So the import wizard isn't even capable of parsing dates that come from SQL Server. Really? Really?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added details (realized my description wasn't correct after revisiting the package I had issues with):

The import thing IS pretty bad.

In my case I had incoming data with form matching  SQL Server type 126 / ISO8601. That is, in T-SQL, this form:

```
select convert ( varchar(100), getdate(), 126 )

--> 2009-12-22T16:29:22.123
```

I was able to import with SSIS using two steps:

1. Replace the "T" with a space " ", using SSIS Derived Column with expression:

   REPLACE(DateColumn,"T"," ")
2. Cast the result to database timestamp [DT_DBTIMESTAMP] using the data conversion transform

Apologies if I caused any confusion.

Comment: So would I have to save it as an SSIS package and then go in and edit the conversion of that field?

Comment: Yes, you can do it with a column transform in the package that the Wizard barfs out.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Obnoxious that I need to go to those lengths to parse a date. But I feel better knowing that it wasn't something obvious I was missing.